Previously installed windows aren't taped/foamed
I'm working through remodels on my house, and I'm moving onto new trim for some existing windows. The windows appear to be relatively new compared to the house (house built in 87, windows are clearly not original). As I removed the existing sill for these windows, I noticed that there was no sill sealing tape or foam installed beneath the window.
Is there any in-place remedy I can apply here or is the best option to remove the window, prep the opening properly, and replace the window?

It's hard to say from that picture whether the window is flashed correctly on the outside.  But there should be some foam between the bottom of the window and the 2x4 to prevent air infiltration.

Taping or flashing would be done on the exterior of the window, then the exterior finish is installed, ( siding, stucco, etc.)  You cannot tell if that work was done from the inside.
Unless you know that the windows are not performing well, (leaking, drafty...) there is no reason to remove them. Just use the appropriate  window and door foam sealant on the interior side.

As you know, evidence of and damage from water leaks on the outside can take a long time to manifest.  OP said all the windows were replaced.  I would consider pulling the exterior siding (or whatever the outside covering is) off one of windows and see if it was flashed correctly.  That will give him some indication whether the lack of foam is just an oversight or evidence of a shoddy installation.

I follow the words of my father, " If it isn't broke, don't fix it.".

I'll just add that it's very important to use the low-expansion foam that's specifically made for window and door frames. The regular stuff can deform the window and make it totally unusable.
